# 文字列変数で持ってるパターンで全置換したい

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

```
s = 'xyzxyz';
p = 'xyz';
console.log(s.replace(p, 'abc'));      // => abcxyz
```

で最初の１個しか置換してくれません

```
console.log(s.replace(/xyz/g, 'abc')); // => abcabc
```

と正規表現を使えば全置換してくれるんですが
パターンの中に変数で持ってる文字列を埋め込む方法ってありますか？

Comment: constructor を使う方法もあります。`console.log(s.replace(new RegExp(p, 'g'), 'abc'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.replaceAll(p, 'abc')` で期待通りになるかと思います。

※ただしIE以外に限る

Comment: node 上で使えなかったんですがバージョンの問題だったみたいでバージョンアップしたら使えました！